# server program exits when i close SSH connection to GCP

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, httpserver

I have an Ubuntu instance on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I want to use it as an HTTP server to access files. I simply use this python command, type it in bash:

> python3 -m http.server 8000

This will run http.server module as a script, construct a simple HTTP server and listen at port 8000.

Problem is that, since I use GCP instance, I must connect to it remotely (for example I use SSH shell provided by GCP). When I close the SSH shell, the python HTTP server will stop. So what should I do to make sure that the server still runs after I close the shell?

I did searched on Google, and I tried to use

> nohup python3 -m http.server 8000 &

This command, I quote, will run the instruction as a background program and persist running after exiting bash. But it seems that this doesn't work for my situation.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Did you try using systemd to use you command as a service on the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) command. I think it's easier to use and also more flexible than `nohup` as you can also reattach processes after detaching then. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/632219/954827) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The `http.server` module is not meant to be a full-fledged webserver.

You'll want to set up something like Apache instead, see [Running a basic Apache web server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache).